# Implements sth with/through?

Tags: prepositions

I'm wondering what is the right preposition to use in the context:

*sth/sb implements sth with/through some method* like for example *the service implements the fault-tolerance with/through automatic backups* ?

I found various options and examples here https://lingohelp.me/preposition-after-verb/implement-in-or-implement-by/ and the "through" fits best for the case, even though it sounds less familiar to my ears than "with".

Could you shed some light on the correct context usage for *through* and *with* when it comes to the *sth/sb implements sth with/through some method* sentence ?

Comment: At least in this limited scope, *with* simply indicates inclusion, whereas _through_ indicates mechanism.

Comment: Thank you, @tripleee, for the explanation.